# Is it okay to use bootstrap nav tabs containing anchor tags in a react app instead of Links of react-router

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-router

I have some genres and relevant Tv shows. Do I necessarily need to convert nav pills into react router Link tags? Or I can use the following bootstrap navigation that is already set up to show the tab content. Would using the later be considered as a bad practice?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-action-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-action" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-action" aria-selected="true">action</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-comedy-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-comedy" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-comedy" aria-selected="false">comedy</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-thrill-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-thrill" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-thrill" aria-selected="false">thrill</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-horror-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-horror" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-horror" aria-selected="false">horror</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-action" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-action-tab">...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-comedy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-comedy-tab">...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-thrill" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-thrill-tab">...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-horror" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-horror-tab">...</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A tags are used for external links while the Link component is used to navigate your rrd routes

Comment: Also, for navigation specifically, you can use the NavLink component which takes an active className or style to match your active route. You can wrap your bootstrap component with it to get the same effect